# nunit test case for db connection

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit

I am new to Nunit framework, C# and dotnet. How to write a test case using Nunit for a db connection. I was not able to find any examples of nunit covering db connections. The test case has to cover checking connection and closing it.

```
namespace TestConnection
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Connection con = new Connection();
            con.ConnectionString = "Server = ab1-vm.app.test.com ;Port = 6080;Database = MY_DB;Schema = SCHM;User id = admin;PWD = *****;level=3;logname=C:\\my_logs";
            Command cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            Encoding e1 = Encoding.Default;
            con.Open();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            try
            {
                string query = "SELECT \"X\", \"Y\", 1 FROM MY_DB..DIM_CONTRACT Z LIMIT 50 ";
                cmd.CommandText = query;
                DataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdr.HasRows)
                {
                    rdr.Read();
                    System.Console.WriteLine(rdr.GetString(0));
                    System.Console.WriteLine(rdr.GetString(1));
                    System.Console.WriteLine(rdr.GetInt32(2));
                }
                rdr.Close();
                con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What you are describing is an *integration test*. Since you are new to testing, I would suggest starting out with a *unit test*. The difference is a unit test only tests a single function of a component *that you created* and an integration test tests interaction between multiple components (some which you may not have created). Unit tests should never depend on things like networks, databases, or file systems to function, so they are easier run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling an assert function `NUnit.Framework.Assert.That(con.State == ConnectionState)` for `con.Open()` and `con.close()`

```cs
namespace TestProject
{
    [TestClass] //Test Framework
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        Connection con = new Connection();

        [TestMethod] //Test Case 1
        public void TestOpenConnection()
        {
            con.ConnectionString = "Server = ab1-vm.app.test.com ;Port = 6080;Database = MY_DB;Schema = SCHM;User id = admin;PWD = *****;level=3;logname=C:\\my_logs";
            con.Open();
            NUnit.Framework.Assert.That(con.State == ConnectionState.Open);
        }

    
        [TestMethod] //Test Case 2
        public void TestCloseConnection()
        {
            con.ConnectionString = "Server = ab1-vm.app.test.com ;Port = 6080;Database = MY_DB;Schema = SCHM;User id = admin;PWD = *****;level=3;logname=C:\\my_logs";
            con.Open();  //open the connection
            con.Close(); //close to test if the connection closes
            NUnit.Framework.Assert.That(con.State == ConnectionState.Closed);
        }
    }
}
```